# How to extract a column items based on other columns in Powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

Below image is a sample data in the excel data table (the whole data is a lot so i only put a few sample datas here):
[image]
[image]

Below is the canvas-app function that I have tried but it does not seems to work :

```
If("1" in Area.buildingID && "1" in Area.'storey ', Distinct(Area,'areaName '))
```

The outcome in the list shown is (the last item Rooftop... should not be shown) For instance, Rooftop [areaName] is from storey 2 and buildingID 1. However, I would like to only extract all areaNames that are from storey 1 and buildingID 1 :

[image]

Desired result is that I would like to extract "areaName" column values based on "storey" and "buildingID" columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would first [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) the table based on the condition that you want:

```
Filter(Area, buildingID = "1", 'storey ' = "1")
```

Then if you want to show only the unique values for the `'areaName '` column you can use the [Distinct function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct) in the result of the first expression:

```
Distinct(Filter(Area, buildingID = "1", 'storey ' = "1"), 'areaName ')
```

Comment: @carlosfigueria can i ask you any questions in the future... i really need help in powerapps as i am a beginner in it :(